Uniswap onchain quotes for v2, v3, v4
Are there onchain (Solidity) quoters that can quote the token price for both Uniswap v2 and v3?
Needed: give a token path and it can quote a price for a given input token amount. E.g. WETH->USDC, PEPE->WETH->USDC or with fee WETH->USDC 5 bps
For viewing purposes only - not to be used within transactions, can be gas inefficient.
Currently the options are

view-quoter-v3 - seems to do only Uniswap v3
SwapRouter02 - legacy, naturally v2 only
And what about v4?

